# General Topology: "Follow your Nose Approach"

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, advice

So, this is definitely a soft question and I apologize. I've been in point set topology for about a week and I have two questions,

Everything spews from definition, so should I dismiss my geometric intuition?

Are definitions meant to be taken as fact, because mostly they seem to come from nowhere?

I am using Munkres. So far I like topology, but the abstraction and my usual visualization isn't working. Should I just pound the definitions into my brain?

Please just comment, i realize this may be really hard to answer, so once a few comments come in (if any), I'll delete the post.

Comment: When dealing with metric spaces, things will usually follow your intuition, but you will find pathological examples that will bend it, hopefully.

Comment: I think reading [There’s more to mathematics than rigour and proofs](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/there%E2%80%99s-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/) by Terry Tao might provide some perspective.

Comment: My two cents on the first question: Intuition should never be dismissed, but one should always be skeptical of it. Indeed, having your intuition foiled by rigorous proof is one of the joys of mathematics.

Comment: The definitions certainly don't come from nowhere. In Euclidean space, many of the properties that we take for granted actually start to diverge once you take assumptions away. Euclidean space can support a metric, which makes separability and second-countability equivalent. But take metrizability away, and you can find a space with a countable dense subset that does $not$ have a countable basis (if you're using Munkres, you will see explicit examples of this).

Comment: The thing topology is the arguments are usually very visual and qualitative, but for them to be possible, a very solid set theoretical foundation has to exist. The first few chapters of Munkres will build this foundation so that later you can discuss things like the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra without caring so much about basic definitions and counterexamples.

Comment: Um, anyway, the point of that is that topology is an abstraction of "familiar" situations, and not the other way around. Geometric intuition is important because it lets you relate the familiar and the abstract in ways that, in practice, turn out to be pretty useful.

Comment: Regarding your question about whether definitions should be taken as fact: Mathematical definitions should be taken like learning a word in a foreign language.  The difference is that often times the word is also used in common speech.  The question of whether or not the definition is "correct" is really a question of whether or not we've correctly identified what is intended when the word is used in common speech.  Sometimes, it turns out the formal definition, even though it might miss this mark, is more useful than what is originally intended and you end up with a steep learning curve.

Comment: did you already took any course on math-analysis?

Comment: I like this question.  I don't think you should delete it, even if it remains unanswered.

Comment: @janmarqz, yes I've taken sequences and series,real analysis and complex variables.

Comment: then your intuitions gotta be good... the important thing is you must not forget the re-definitions that are in topology as well being patient... try to read the famous book: "topology with fear".

Comment: Thanks. And also I can't find a link containing that name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitions do not come from nowhere, but it is unfortunately conventional to omit the rationales behind them.

In topology, popular accounts say that the subject studies properties of spaces that don't change if one stretches and bends them without tearing the.  But then rigorous accounts say that a topology is a collection of subsets, called open sets, satisfying certain conditions.  It seems to me that anyone who doesn't wonder why those are the same thing is not paying attention.

Here's a simple example.  Consider the half-open interval $[0,1)$.  Let the "basic" open sets in this space be the intersections of $[0,1)$ with open intervals, and let open sets be arbitrary unions of "basic" open sets.  Then one has an interval that looks like an interval.  But then alter the definition of "basic" open sets so that every open set containing $0$ as a member includes some set of the form $[0,\varepsilon)\cup(1-\varepsilon,1)$, so that both ends of the interval are included.  Then one has an interval that looks like a circle.  In other words, the way the whole thing is connected together is just a matter of which sets are open.  That enables you to see why the intended meaning of topology is the same as the meaning according to the logically rigorous definition.